Overwrite brush or color resource from another DLL at runtime
I want to overwrite a SolidColorBrush defined in a referenced dll at runtime. The resource is defined in MyStyle.dll.
Styling.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:themes="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/themes">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ...
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors/Colors.xaml" />
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>

Colors.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:themes="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/themes">
    <Color x:Key="MyColor">#66A3B5</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>

In the consuming WPF application it is bound as dynamic resource:
...
<Border Background="{DynamicResource MyBrush}">
    ... content ...
</Border>
...

The ResourceDictionaries are loaded/merged in code in the Application.cs class, right after the Application is instantiated.
LoadComponent(new Uri("/MyStyle;v7.0.0.0;3d70d0e64510241c;component/Styling.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;

At runtime I tried the following:
System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["MyBrush"] = Brushes.Aqua;
... more resources merged in the same way

This changes the resource successfully, but in the UI still the original color is shown.
Changing MyColor does also not work.
When MyColor and MyBrush are defined in the consuming applications App.xaml it works.
EDIT: Added some more background on how the resources are defined and loaded.

Where do you merge the external ResourceDictionary?

In the Application.cs with LoadComponent(...). Edited the question to give more detail.

A general example that requires that the external ResourceDictionary is properly merged into e.g. App.xaml.
You need the name and location of the external ReourceDictionary (pack URI, which you should have if you merge the external resource into your application).
You also need a reference to the ResourceDictionary that the external resources are merged into.
Note, a general solution that will always work is to inject a similar named resource into the lookup tree before or at the level of the ResourceDictionary tha merges the external resources into your application. WPF will pick the first resource that has a matching resource key.
To directly manipulate the ResourceDictionary you can use the following code. Note that it will only replace the runtime instance and not overwrite the actual .xaml file. It's usually not what you want, so I'm just saying.
private void ChangeExternalResource(
  Uri resourceDictioanryUri, 
  object resourceKey, 
  object resource, 
  ResourceDictionary mergingDictionary)
{
  StreamResourceInfo resourceStreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceDictioanryUri);
  using Stream bamlResourceStream = resourceStreamInfo.Stream;
  _ = bamlResourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  using var bamlReader = new Baml2006Reader(bamlResourceStream);
  var resourceDictionaryCopy = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(bamlReader);

  // Modify the created ResourceDictionary instance
  resourceDictionaryCopy[resourceKey] = resource;

  // Replace the merged originally merged ResourceDictionary instance
  ResourceDictionary originalREsourceDictionary = mergingDictionary.MergedDictionaries.First(mergedDictionary => IsEqual(resourceDictionaryCopy, mergedDictionary));
  int mergedDictionaryIndex = mergingDictionary.MergedDictionaries.IndexOf(originalREsourceDictionary);
  Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[mergedDictionaryIndex] = resourceDictionaryCopy;
}

private static bool IsEqual(ResourceDictionary resourceDictionaryCopy, ResourceDictionary mergedDictionary)
{
  return !mergedDictionary.Keys
    .Cast<object>()
    .Except(resourceDictionaryCopy.Keys.Cast<object>())
    .Any();
}

The following example has an external ResourceDictionary named Brushes.xaml and located in the external ExternalResources.dll  aseembly. The external resource is merged into the application's App.xaml resource dictionary:
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ExternalResources;component/Brushes.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>

var externalResourceDictionaryUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ExternalResources;component/Brushes.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
object resourceKey = "MyBrush";
object replacementResource = Brushes.Orange;
ResourceDictionary mergingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources;

ChangeExternalResource(externalResourceDictionaryUri, resourceKey, replacementResource, mergingResourceDictionary);


Thank you, but how to determine the "externalResourceDictionaryUri" if the ResourceDictionary is nested in others? Or is only the Path/Uri in the DLL relevant and not the hierarchy from merging?

You need to specify the Uri for the .xaml file. The merging hierarchy is not relevant except tha you need to know which .xaml file you have to load in order to get the correct top level ResourceDictionary. You need knwoledge about where the resources are located if you want to replace them. When looking up the resource by key, the ResourceDictionary will automatically search the merged dictionaries.

We could lookup a resource by reflecting the provided assembly This is not very efficient. That's why I have implemented it the way it is. Does that not meet your requirement?

I can modify the code if you only want to provide the assembly. Because you have to merge the external resources into your application you already know the .xaml URI. That was the reason for my decision to implement it more efficiently by skipping the search for the correct .xaml file..

Okay, it turns out, that the Styling.xaml ResourceDictionary is merged several times to get the designer work. When I look inte the running Application with Snoop, there is the changed Brush top level and various other ResourcesDictionaries merged and nested. All others containing the original, not changed, Brush. I tried it with SharedDictionaries from WPF Tutorial, but no success yet.

Ah, I see. Yeah, that's a bit of an issue as each merged ResourceDictionary provides its own instances. Then give some time. I won't make it today, but I can modify the code to crawl a provided DLL for all occurrences of a particular .xaml file to replace a set of resources. I think that's a more graceful solution than to have a static resource provider. A static resource dictionary may be ok in a small project with few static controls. But in a bigger application this can cost memory. Lots of memory. It's basically a memory leak.

Talking about perfroamnce, it's genrally a good practice to avoid defining resources in local ResourceDictionaries. If you define or merge resources at application level (App.xaml) you basically get shared resources. The point is, that e.g. a custom MyButton has resources defined, each instance of MyButton will create its own ResourceDictionary instance. That will slow down the application fast. If you can, you should avoid such practice and merge at application level. Application resources are globally available. And you eliminate the current issue you are having.
